# iconv install failure ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, iconv

I've got huge headache trying to install iconv gem on ruby.

```
gem install iconv -- --http-proxy http://login:password.@proxy:8080 --with-iconv-dir=\D:\libiconv
```

Result is:

```
    ERROR:  Error installing iconv:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/iconv-1.0.4/ext/iconv D:/InstantRails/ruby/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20161020-2784-1sz8avf.rb extconf.rb --http-proxy http://bche:f1r305sty5.@proxy.isd.dp.ua:8080 --with-iconv-dir=D:/libiconv
checking for rb_enc_get() in ruby/encoding.h... yes
checking for rb_sys_fail_str() in ruby.h... yes
checking for iconv() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv() in -liconv... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

I've downloaded all source files that possible. Please help

Comment: What does the log file say?

Comment: Command: ruby script/server -e production -p 999

Comment: trace:
D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require': cannot load such file -- iconv (LoadError)
        from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
        from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from D:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from

Answer (score 0):

Iconv has been deprecated since Ruby v 1.9.3, only old gems use it these days and you would better update or replace these.
If you use it yourself, the same functionality can be reached using `String.encode` or `String.scrub` (Ruby -v ~> 2.1).

I'm not saying it is impossible to install it but I question the effort you are gonna spend in it isn't better used elsewhere. Had the same problem installing Sqlite in Ruby 2.3.0 and succeeded only after trying multiple times and after a few weeks.

Comment: I had an old project and I even not know where that extension included to delete.

Comment: An error that I've got is: ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require': cannot load such file -- iconv (LoadError)

Comment: make a new question with your code and the error it generates (full stacktrace) so that we can reproduce it, we'll try to find a solution without iconv

Comment: make a new question - it realy is - with the complete backtrace AND your code, this one was incomplete and unreadable in a comment